# regular expression text between two sign

Tags: java, regex

I have a text and I want to replace variables in it with proper values and my variables located between two @. When I use [/(?m)@.*?@/] to get these texts it also returns texts before and after first and last @. how could I get texts only between these two @ sign. thanks in advance.
I use String.split("") method in Java.
for example I want use on the following String:

> this is @the best@ possible way @t@o do result!!!

and I wanna get these two results:

> the best
>
> t

Comment: Use this `@(.*?)@` regex and get the chars inbetween `@` from group index 1 .

Comment: I may have multiple variables.

Comment: A more precise regex is both faster and more accurate: `@([^@]*)@`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you can use this regex to grab value **between first and second `@`**:

```
String repl = input.replaceFirst("(?m)^[^@]*@([^@]*)@.*$" "$1");
```

To grab value between **first and last `@`**:

```
String repl = input.replaceFirst("(?m)^[^@]*@(.*?)@[^@]*$" "$1");
```

To find multiple matches use `Pattern`, `Matcher`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@([^@]*)@"):
Matcher m = p.matcher(p);
while (m.find()) {
     System.out.prinln(m.group(1));
}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zH2yM1/1)

Comment: I may have multiple variables.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this. Better to add more examples in the question.

Comment: The lookarounds will print all three matches, you want a capturing group instead =)

Comment: Thanks @hwnd, earlier I assumed OP is trying to capture all texts between `@` and `@` including middle one.

Answer (score 1):

`Split()` is the wrong tool to use here, use the [`Matcher()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) method to do this instead.

```
String s  = "this is @the best@ possible way @t@o do result!!!";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@([^@]*)@");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
the best
t
```